# Multiple mediation using Process for SPSS - intercept for direct effect significance

Tags: p-value, mediation

I hope someone can help! I've been trying to teach myself to use the Process tool for SPSS with a multiple mediation model (model 6), and I think I've cracked most of it and have established a model. The one problem I'm stuck on is the intercept significance for the model without mediators (direct effect). The overall regression for this is significant, however the intercept (constant) is not.

My question is: what does this mean? And does it mean that the model itself is not significant?

[image]

Sorry if this is a basic question - as I said I'm trying to teach myself and my grasp of statistics isn't as good as I wish it was!

Comment: Why do you want to have a significant intercept? The meaning is that you have no evidence that your regression line is not passing through the origin: why should it be a problem in your case?